# SQL Pivot when there is no matching field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table structure which generated using a trigger. Action describes insert or update.

| AuditID | PKColname | PK | FieldName | OldValue | NewValue | Action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | VehicleID | 1 | VehicleID |  | 1 | Insert |
| 2 | VehicleID | 1 | VehicleMake |  | Mercedes | Insert |
| 3 | VehicleID | 1 | VehicleMake | Mercedes | Toyota | Update |
| 4 | VehicleID | 2 | VehicleMake | Ferrari | Aston Martin | Update |
| 5 | VehicleID | 2 | ServiceInterval | 25000KM | 50000KM | Update |

My knowledge with pivot table is very limited how can I get the following output.

| PK | Action | VehicleID | VehicleMake_NewValue | ServiceInterval_NewValue | VehicleMake_OldValue | ServiceInterval_OldValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Insert | 1 | Mercedes | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | Update | NULL | Toyota | NULL | Mercedes | NULL |
| 2 | Update | NULL | Aston Martin | 50000KM | Ferrari | 25000KM |

What I have done is using this

```
DECLARE @NewValues TABLE
(
    [VehicleID]             VARCHAR(255),
    [CustomerID]            VARCHAR(255),
    [RegistrationNumber]    VARCHAR(255),
    [FleetNumber]           VARCHAR(255),
    [EngineNumber]          VARCHAR(255)
)
INSERT INTO @NewValues([VehicleID], [CustomerID], [RegistrationNumber], [FleetNumber], [EngineNumber])
SELECT p.[VehicleID],p.[CustomerID],p.[RegistrationNumber],p.[FleetNumber], p.[EngineNumber]
FROM
(
  SELECT p.NewValue, p.FieldName
   FROM dbo.VehicleAudit AS p
) AS j
PIVOT
(
  MAX(NewValue) FOR FieldName IN ([VehicleID],[CustomerID],[RegistrationNumber],[FleetNumber],[EngineNumber])
) AS p;


DECLARE @OldValues TABLE
(
    [CustomerID]            VARCHAR(255),
    [RegistrationNumber]    VARCHAR(255),
    [FleetNumber]           VARCHAR(255),
    [EngineNumber]          VARCHAR(255)
)
INSERT INTO @OldValues([CustomerID], [RegistrationNumber], [FleetNumber], [EngineNumber])
SELECT d.[CustomerID],d.[RegistrationNumber],d.[FleetNumber], d.[EngineNumber]
FROM
(
  SELECT d.OldValue, d.FieldName
   FROM dbo.VehicleAudit AS d
) AS j
PIVOT
(
  MAX(OldValue) FOR FieldName IN ([CustomerID],[RegistrationNumber],[FleetNumber], [EngineNumber])
) AS d
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO is not a place to write code for you, but rather meant for you to learn how to solve particular issues you encounter while working on your code.

Comment: @SchmitzIT please see above

Comment: So what in that code is not working? What error messages do you get? What part of the result is not matching what you expect? Please keep in mind we do not have your sample data or database schema, so it's hard for us to guess what's wrong if you do not supply that information.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Looks like MS SQL Server?)

Comment: @jarlh I am using MSSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select action, pk,
       max(case when FieldName = 'VehicleID' then NewValue end) as VehicleID,
       max(case when FieldName = 'VehicleMake' then NewValue end) as VehicleMake_NewValue,
       max(case when FieldName = 'ServiceInterval' then NewValue end) as ServiceInterval_NewValue,
       max(case when FieldName = 'VehicleMake' then OldValue end) as VehicleMake_OldValue,
       max(case when FieldName = 'ServiceInterval' then OldValue end) as ServiceInterval_OldValue
from t
group by pk, action;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6c60b66b22604cc55da104439aeab344) is a db<>fiddle showing that it returns the results you specify in the question.